Ignoring merged rows when reading an excel workbook
I have made a python script to read the rows in an excel cell and divide them in workbooks
The problem is that in one of the scripts the row labels are in row 3, the first 2 rows are made of merged cells, the 1st row is taken as the label for the dataframe.
I want the first 2 rows to be ignored and only row 3 and below to be read but the goal is to make this dynamic for other cases like this where top cells are merged.
def read_excel_file(file_buffer):
    # Load the Excel file using openpyxl
    wb = load_workbook(file_buffer, data_only=True)

    # Get a list of all workbook names
    workbook_names = wb.sheetnames
    
    workbooks = {}

    # Iterate over each workbook
    for workbook_name in workbook_names:
        # Read the workbook into a pandas DataFrame
        workbook_df = pd.read_excel(file_buffer, sheet_name=workbook_name)

        # Add the workbook to the dictionary
        workbooks[workbook_name] = workbook_df

    # Return the dictionary of workbooks
    return workbooks


Please add a small example of what the data looks like in one of the sheets + the expected output (workbook_df) based on that example.

Why not just read it with openpyxl. You started using it so go ahead with that route. Should be fast enough and possibly faster. Plus you have more control

ws.iter_rows(min_row=3)

Seems you want to check what rows contain merged cells then skip those rows.
You can check the rows that exist in the merged cells finding the max row in the list then skip rows up to that row in the read_excel.
import pandas as pd
from openpyxl import load_workbook


file_buffer = "merged.xlsx"
workbook_name = 'Sheet1'

wb = load_workbook(file_buffer)
ws = wb[workbook_name]

### Get the max row that exists in the merged cells list
max_merged_row = max([merge.max_row for merge in ws.merged_cells])
print(max_merged_row)

### Create Dataframe skipping the rows that have merged cells
workbook_df = pd.read_excel(file_buffer, sheet_name=workbook_name, skiprows=max_merged_row)



